# How to make output file of one script, as an input file for the another script?

Tags: perl

I am currently working on a project where in I am using Perl language to create command line application of one online tool.
There are total nine modules (for each module there is separate Perl script).

This **Command Line** Application should work in the following way-

1. Out of these nine modules user would be able to select any number of modules. (in short pipeline should be built).
2. after running first selected module, output files are generated.
3. output file of first module should be taken as an input file by the next module selected by the user.

My doubt is how we can make output file of first module as an input file for the next selected module.
It will be a great help if you solve my doubt as I am new to Perl programming.
Thanking you!

Comment: using pipe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765311/how-to-read-to-and-write-from-a-pipe-in-perl

Comment: Please dont use all caps. IT MEANS SHOUTING...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to explain more about the pairing. Please give more sample input. Taking the tour is highly recommended and you definitly should read [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) How to Ask.

Answer (score 0):

Tamar is right. You can use pipe command: "|". You can do this no matter if you're using windows or a unix based operating system.

Here's a simple example of what you're doing:

Code to output data 
out.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "output.txt";
my $data = "gasp";

unless(-e $file){
    open(my $fh, '>', $file);
    print $fh $data;
    close $fh;
}
```

Code that takes input file 
in.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $gaspage = <STDIN>;
chomp $gaspage;
print $gaspage."\n";
```

Then you just run it with the commands below that can be run within your perl application or just in the terminal:

```
perl out.pl
cat output.pl | in.pl
```