# Run a program and capture its output

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Perl script that runs a python script but i need to pass information back to the Perl script.
Anyone can help me to achieve this?

This is my code so far

```
open(my $py, "|-", "python2 /home/pi/myRead.py") or die "Cannot run Python script: $!";
while (<$py>) {
    $newCard = $py;
}
close($py);
```

Comment: You keep overwriting `$newCard` instead of appending to it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765311/how-to-read-to-and-write-from-a-pipe-in-perl

Comment: `"-|"` is for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $newCard = `python2 /home/pi/myRead.py`;
```

Comment: I swear this was my first try and didn't work. worked now. TY

Comment: Don't use backticks.  Use `qx`.  eg. `my $newCard = qx@ python /home/pi/myRead.py@;`

Comment: @William Pursell, Why??? `\`...\`` is short for `qx\`...\``, which is short for `readpipe(qq\`...\`)`.

Comment: @ikegami.  For the same reason one uses `$()` instead of backticks in a shell script.  Better readability.

Comment: @William Pursell, You could argue that `qx(...)` is more readable, but that's not what you recommended.

Comment: Argue on what basis? `qq@@` adds noise, unfamiliarity and complexity, all *deterrents* to readability. On top of that, it changes the meaning of `@`, a huge reduction in readability. Finally, `qq@@` also reduces usability (by preventing the interpolation of arrays). All that, and no benefits are added. It clearly hurts readability (and usability). /// On the other hand, `qq()` also adds noise and unfamiliarity, but also adds balanced delimiters which adds a modicum of readability. Enough to overcome the noise and unfamiliarity? debatable.

Comment: Backticks in perl/shellscripts cannot be nested. Neither can `qx@@`. When you tell people not to use backticks, you give the impression that `qx` is somehow intrinsically different. The `qx` proponent voice is so loud it made me think `qx` had real advantages, like better argument parsing. It does not. To get strong argument handling, you need to use `open()`, `open2()`, or `open3()`.