# Difficulty formatting xml file in Perl

Tags: perl, io, ipc

I'm not really a Perl developer, but I have to parse/modify several files, so figured Perl would be a good choice for this adhoc script... So I apologize in advance, I'm probably missing an important fundamental concept (I actually had ChatGPT generate the initial script for me).

For some reason, my script isn't able to use `xmllint` or seemingly any other library or CLI executable to concisely (without specifying the schema of the XML) format my XML file... I'm wondering if this has anything to do with IPC and piping of output/input data (concepts I don't worry about in TypeScript, C#, etc)?

Here is some attempted code on my end:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Check if the command-line argument is provided
if (@ARGV != 1) {
    die "Usage: $0 <csproj_file>\n";
}

my $csproj_file = $ARGV[0];

# Format the entire XML file using xmllint
open my $xmllint_pipe, '|-', 'xmllint --format --recover - ' or die "Cannot open pipe to xmllint: $!";
print $xmllint_pipe $content;  # Send the original XML content to xmllint for formatting
close $xmllint_pipe;  # Close the pipe

# Write the updated and formatted content back to the file
open my $output_fh, '>encoding(utf8)', $csproj_file or die "Could not open file '$csproj_file' for writing: $!";
print $output_fh $content;  # Write the formatted content to the file
close $output_fh;  # Close the filehandle

my $formatted_content = `xmllint --format $csproj_file`;

# Write the updated and formatted content back to the file
open my $output_fh, '>encoding(utf8)', $csproj_file or die "Could not open file '$csproj_file' for writing: $!";
print $output_fh $content;  # Write the formatted content to the file
close $output_fh;  # Close the filehandle
```

Basic use-case: I just want to fix up the spacing/tabbing in some XML files that I'm editing via script (it's not super important, but figure I may as well if it's easy).

Comment: Why don't you just use the shell like bash? Can you share a sample input/expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the hint/suggestion. Just got it to work by using the underlying shell-scripting language on my system. Sample input would just be any XML file not properly indented, and the output would be properly indented. (Using this script to do some find/replace of one syntax/version of doing things to another kind, using regex.... happy to learn from any other general suggestions you may have.)

Comment: There's a good technique in https://stackoverflow.com/q/10765311/2766176

Answer (score 3):

What I would do, no need using Perl at all:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -v # for verbosity: display executed commands
xmllint --format "$csproj_file" | sponge "$csproj_file"
```

`sponge` from `more-utils` to edit on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want using [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML), the standard binding for **libxml2**.
Much as I tried, I couldn't get XML::LibXML's [toString](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod#toString) method to output indentations, so I opted for [XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint;

my $csproj_file = shift @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 <csproj_file>\n" unless $csproj_file;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file($csproj_file);
my $pp  = XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new(indent_string => '  ');

$pp->pretty_print($doc); # modified in-place

$doc->toFile($csproj_file);
```

Comment: I'll work up something in [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) and post it.

Comment: I'd suggest to not mention `XML::Simple` -- it's not simple, it's hard to use, it's been advised against by its own author decades ago (who even wrote a nice tutorial for XML::LibXML), and there's been volumes written here against it since it was important and popular back in the day so people keep coming with questions about it.  I'd suggest to just remove that part of your answer

Comment: XML::Simple is awful for reading XML files, but that doesn't come close to how terrible it is at generating output! Your XML::Simple program doesn't come close to working. It can't even handle the simplest of XML documents (`<root></root>`). Did you do no testing? Seems like you should have given how many warnings there is against using this module! If you remove that garbage from your post, let me know and I'll remove by downvote.

Comment: @ikegami I tested it with the **foo.xml** example in Simple's Quick Start section, worked fine for me. On that example, it produces the same output as XML::LibXML. It would have been nice if the `$format` option to `toFile()` worked for me and I could've skipped the PrettyPrint module.

Comment: Re "*i I tested it with the foo.xml example in Simple's Quick Start section, worked fine for me*", No, it didn't. [That's not remotely true.](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/8c5d7e8d082c12215cafb8b74ed04de6) 1) It literally changes the root node from `config` to `opt`. 2) It changes one of the `address` elements into an `address` attribute. 3) It reorders the `server` elements. 4) The attributes are also re-ordered. This is not actually a bug, but it's possibly inconvenient.

Comment: Re "*I could've skipped the PrettyPrint module.*", XML::LibXML does not make unsafe changes to the document. Adding text nodes between tags isn't safe, even if they only contain whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

So I took @Gilles Quénot 's hint, and just used the underlying shell-scripting language on my platform (which is either cmd or PowerShell as I'm currently on Windows).

Just went for a simple solution to the XML formatting. Not the most efficient, but very easy to read. Below is the relevant modifications that I made to get it to work:

```perl
my $tmp_filepath = $csproj_file . '_tmp';

print "xmllint --format $csproj_file > $tmp_filepath";

system("xmllint --format $csproj_file > $tmp_filepath");

print "move $tmp_filepath $csproj_file";

system("move $tmp_filepath $csproj_file");
```

Basically: just use a temporary file, and run basic CMD commands to: first, format the XML and save in temp file; second, rename the temp filename to the original filename.

Comment: You'd want to check that `xmllint` call for errors after it completes, before you overwrite the original.  That's one virtue of creating a temporary first, so that you have a chance to see whether it all worked before you blow away (overwrite) your good original file.  Or, at least, save the original first (perhaps copy it to `name.orig` or `orig_name` or some such).